# Definitions-App throws an exception on start after update to Magnolia 5.5.7

Tags: java, spring, maven, dependencies, magnolia

I'm testing a possible upgrade of Magnolia to Version 5.5.7 (from Version 5.3.14), i got it so far that our project works completely and i get no warnings on startup anymore.

I followed the recommended update steps stated in Magnolia's documentation:
https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Updating+Magnolia

But when i try to open the definitions app the sub-app "overview" it uses throws a NullPointerException and i can't figure out why.

The Error persists even when i delete and recreate the entire repository so i think it has something to do with dependencies, unfortunately i don't know a lot about dependency implications in Magnolia i'm just using the packages and versions recommended plus what we used before to compile the project.

Stacktrace:

```
    ERROR agnolia.ui.framework.app.AppInstanceControllerImpl: Sub-app overview failed to start: null java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Comparators$NaturalOrderComparator.compare(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Comparators$NaturalOrderComparator.compare(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimSort.binarySort(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.sort(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.SortedOps$RefSortingSink.end(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.DistinctOps$1$2.end(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source)
    at info.magnolia.definitions.app.overview.toolbar.ToolbarPresenter.getModuleNames(ToolbarPresenter.java:98)
```

POM-File dependencies:

parent:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <skipTests>false</skipTests>
    <javaVersion>1.8</javaVersion>
    <magnoliaVersion>5.5.7</magnoliaVersion>
    <blossomVersion>3.1.4</blossomVersion>
    <magnoliaDAMVersion>2.2.7</magnoliaDAMVersion>
    <springVersion>4.3.1.RELEASE</springVersion>
    <luceneVersion>3.6.2</luceneVersion>
    <siteVersion>1.1.2</siteVersion>
    <stkVersion>3.0.2</stkVersion>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>info.magnolia.bundle</groupId>
       <artifactId>magnolia-bundle-parent</artifactId>
       <version>${magnoliaVersion}</version>
       <type>pom</type>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>magnolia.nexus.public</id>
        <url>https://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/content/groups/public/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>vaadin.nexus.public</id>
        <url>http://vaadin.com/nexus/content/repositories/vaadin-addons/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

webapp:

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- magnolia -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia.blossom</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-module-blossom</artifactId>
        <version>${blossomVersion}</version>
         <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>info.magnolia.ui</groupId>
                <artifactId>magnolia-ui-framework</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>info.magnolia.ui</groupId>
                <artifactId>magnolia-ui-admincentral</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia.documentation</groupId>
        <artifactId>app-searchaliases</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.8</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-empty-webapp</artifactId>
        <version>${magnoliaVersion}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-empty-webapp</artifactId>
        <version>${magnoliaVersion}</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-core</artifactId>
        <version>${magnoliaVersion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-rendering</artifactId>
        <version>${magnoliaVersion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-templating</artifactId>
        <version>${magnoliaVersion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-templating-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>${magnoliaVersion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-module-data</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia.ui</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-ui-framework</artifactId>
        <version>${magnoliaVersion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia.ui</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-ui-admincentral</artifactId>
        <version>${magnoliaVersion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-module-scheduler</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

     <!-- legacy/compatibility -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-module-legacy-admininterface</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-core-compatibility</artifactId>
        <version>${magnoliaVersion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-module-public-user-registration</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia.pur</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-module-public-user-registration-legacy</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia.devdect</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-module-device-detection</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia.definitions</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-definitions-app</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- /legacy/compatibility -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia.templating</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-templating-essentials-models</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-module-categorization</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia.categorization</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-categorization-support</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-module-rssaggregator</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-module-groovy</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia.dam</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-dam</artifactId>
        <version>${magnoliaDAMVersion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia.dam</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-dam-api</artifactId>
        <version>${magnoliaDAMVersion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia.dam</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-dam-app</artifactId>
        <version>${magnoliaDAMVersion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia.dam</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-dam-compatibility</artifactId>
        <version>${magnoliaDAMVersion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia.dam</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-dam-core</artifactId>
        <version>${magnoliaDAMVersion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia.dam</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-dam-jcr</artifactId>
        <version>${magnoliaDAMVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>

        <groupId>info.magnolia.dam</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-dam-templating</artifactId>
        <version>${magnoliaDAMVersion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia.ui</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-ui-contentapp</artifactId>
        <version>${magnoliaVersion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-module-activation</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-module-webdav</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-core</artifactId>
        <version>${magnoliaVersion}</version>
        <type>test-jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-module-imaging</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-imaging-support</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>info.magnolia.site</groupId>
      <artifactId>magnolia-site</artifactId>
      <version>${siteVersion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>info.magnolia.site</groupId>
      <artifactId>magnolia-site-app</artifactId>
      <version>${siteVersion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia.cache</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-cache-app</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.7-SNAPSHOT</version>
     </dependency>
    <!-- needed for public registration / form-module -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-module-mail</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-module-form</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-resource-loader</artifactId>
        <version>${magnoliaVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-module-forum</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-module-inplace-templating</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia.log</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-log-tools</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
     </dependency>
    <!-- provided stuff -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- TEST -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdom2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.3.Final</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.33</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mariadb.jdbc/mariadb-java-client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>nl.captcha</groupId>
        <artifactId>simplecaptcha</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1-mvn</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-analyzers</artifactId>
        <version>${luceneVersion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-highlighter</artifactId>
        <version>${luceneVersion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Do anyone have a clue for me of why this error appears?

**Update:**

Updating Magnolia to Version 5.6 with blossom 3.2 fixed the error for me

Answer (score -1):

I'd guess you ran into https://jira.magnolia-cms.com/browse/PSWDMNGR-7

Try to exclude password manager module or replace it's version with [1.0.1-SNAPSHOT](https://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/#nexus-search;quick~magnolia-module-password-manager) that has this issue fixed (don't take 1.2, that's compatible only w/ Magnolia 5.6).

HTH,
Jan

Comment: Unfortunatly i can't see this ticket, also i'm not using the password manager module in my pom at all, do you mean it gets installed by default or is part of another package? if so where to add the exclusion?